# URL change when the submit is click twice PHP

Tags: php

I'm trying to post values to `2.php`, when the inputs are `null` it will go back to `1.php` and then display an error message, the URL changed to `1.php/?error=1`.

The problem is that when I accidentally click the submit button twice, the URL changes to `/1.php/2.php`, any idea?

**`1.php`:**

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['error']) && $_GET['error'] == 1) 
{
    echo "Error";
}
?>

<form method="Post" action="2.php">
<input type="text" name="firstname">
<input type="text" name="secondname">
<input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
?>
```

**`2.php`:**

```
if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
{
    $first = $_POST["firstname"];
    $second = $_POST["secondname"];

    if($first == "" || $second == "")
    {
        header("Location: 1.php/?error=1");
        die();
    }
    else
    {
        echo $first;
        echo $second;

    }

}
```

Comment: The issue is probably the slash after the `.php` and before the question mark. Try removing it.

Comment: That works, 1.php?error=1, Can you explain why? Sorry im newbie in php. thx

Comment: Add that slash essentially says the file that will be handling the request is in a directory *below* 1.php and being handled by a file called index.php which is the default file used when none is specified. By removing the slash you append the query string to the appropriate page thus solving your issue.

Comment: Am I doing a server side validation? I'm a little bit confused between client and server side validation. I hope you can help me.. thx

Comment: Yes. That is server side validation.

Answer (score 0):

A) Use a BASE tag in your HTML

```
<head>
    <base href="http://127.0.0.1/">
```

or

B) prepend a slash to each link

```
<form action="/2.php">
```

or

C) disable the button after the first click

```
<script>
    document.forms[0].addEventListener( 'submit', function() {
        var submitButton = document.forms[0].querySelector( '[type="submit"]' );
        submitButton.setAttribute( 'disabled', 'disabled' );
    }, false );
<script>
```

…or some combination of those.

Answer (score 0):

Amend the redirect code to;

```
header("Location: ./1.php?error=1");
```